# Question about isomorphism given by the Serre Spectral sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences, fibration

For context I am trying to reprove lemma 1.6 in Weibel's K-book chapter IV. The point about which I have question is the following. Suppose we have a fibration $F\to X\to Y$, with $F$ acyclic, then using the Serre spectral sequence we can see that the homology (with coefficient in a $\pi_1(Y)$ module M) of $X$ and of $Y$ are abstractly isomorphic. 
My question is, is there any way to show that the isomorphism is given by the map $X\to Y$ of the fibration? I feel like this should be the case, but am not comfortable enough to prove it myself.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Serre spectral sequence the edge homomorphism
$$H_p(X;M)\to E^\infty_{p,0}\subset E^2_{p,0}=H_p(Y;M)$$
is the map induced by $X\to Y$.

If $F$ is acyclic then the Serre spectral sequence collapses at the second page, which has only a single column, so the edge homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5):

$\require{AMScd}$
I think you can use the fact that the Serre spectral sequence converges *naturally*; here is a rough argument: Consider the following commutative diagram of fibrations

\begin{CD}
F @>>> X @>f>> Y\\
@VcVV  @VfVV  @VV\text{id}V\\
\text{pt} @>>> Y @>>\text{id}> Y
\end{CD}

This tells us that we have a "diagram" of converging spectral sequences as follows:

\begin{CD}
H_p(Y; H_q(F;M)) @. \Longrightarrow @. H_{p+q}(X;M)\\
  @VH_p(\text{id};H_q(c;M))VV @.   @VVH_{p+q}(f;M)V\\
H_p(Y; H_q(\text{pt};M)) @. \Longrightarrow @. H_{p+q}(Y;M)
\end{CD}

In particular, the left map is an isomorphism by acyclicity of $F$ and it induces isomorphisms on all further pages of the spectral sequence. Thus, the map $f_*$ on the right is an isomorphism as well. As a reference, you can use Hatcher's [chapter on the Serre spectral sequence](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/SSAT/SSch1.pdf), pages 18ff.